# What function do I use to replace the depreciated escapeJs()?

Tags: javascript, magento2.4, phtml, phpstorm

I am using Magento2.4. In my phtml template, I am trying to escape an a argument that is being passed into a javascript file via requireJS, but PhpStorm is warning me that escapeJs() is depreciated. What would be the correct function to use if escapeJs() is depreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the block has **$escaper** already, you need to use that. Here is the example:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
 */
?>
```

Now you can use:

```
$escaper->escapeJs()
```

Comment: Thank you very much!